# Apache Camel SFTP file download from specific directory

Tags: apache-camel, uri, sftp, camel-ftp

I used FTP component of camel but it could not download the files that I want.

```
<camel:endpoint id="ftpNotificationDownload" uri="sftp:/11.1.1.1://app/as?username=aa&amp;password=1111&amp;fastExistsCheck=true&amp;localWorkDirectory=C:\\asd&amp;download=true&amp;throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&amp;delay=4000&amp;useFixedDelay=true"/>
```

I want all the files and folders to be downloaded under my local folder so I did not put filename option.

When I give the host name as `11.1.1.1`, it works but when I set directory after host name like `11.1.1.1:/app/directory`, it does not work.

I have checked SFTP server and it is up.

Comment: Is this rly the uri u use? If yes maybe it is a typo in your uri? Try sftp://11.1.1.1/app/directory without : after the ip address.

Comment: Would help if you elaborate on "it does not work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be a colon (`:`) after the host name in the `uri`. And probably not even one of the two slashes. On the other hand, you are missing one slash after the `sftp:`.

See [Apache Camels URIs syntax](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ftp-component.html#_uri_format).

```
sftp://[username@]hostName[:port]/directoryName[?options]
```

Try

```
sftp://11.1.1.1/app/as?...
```

Note that this is true for any URI, not just Camel.